# MATLAB : Compile a 32-bit shared library from a 64-bit Windows with 64-bit MATLAB installed

Tags: matlab

I want to compile a **c++ shared library** within **64-Bit Matlab**. But I need **32-Bit** version of the library because I have 32-Bit visual studio ! How can I do this?
Is is possible to force `deploytool` to compile libraries in 32 bit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to have the 32-bit version of MATLAB to create a 32-bit library. You can install 32-bit MATLAB on a 64-bit operating system. If you are in maintenance with your MATLAB license, you should be able to download the 32-bit version from MathWorks.

Comment: This is indeed the way to go, note that you can run a 32 bit and a 64 bit version on the same sytem if required.